# base64 url safe removes =

Tags: java, base64, padding, apache-commons-codec

The following code(using commons codec Base64):

```
  byte[] a = Hex.decodeHex("9349c513ed080dab".toCharArray());
  System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(a));
  System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(a));
```

gives the following output:

```
k0nFE-0IDas         //should be k0nFE-0IDas=
k0nFE+0IDas=
```

`Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(a)` returns `k0nFE-0IDas` instead of `k0nFE-0IDas=`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because that's what it's [documented](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString-byte:A-) to do:

> **Note: no padding is added.**

The `=` characters at the end of a base64 string are called padding. They're used to make sure that the final string's length is a multiple of 4 characters - but they're not really required, in terms of information theory, so it's reasonable to remove them so long as you then convert the data back to binary using a method which doesn't expect padding. The Apache Codec `Base64` class claims it transparently handles both regular and URL-safe base64, so presumably *does* handle a lack of padding.

Comment: I missed the doc. Thanks